# C# Encrypt/Decrypt from Java AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes, sha1

I'm facing an issue trying to Decrypt a string which has been encrypted in Java with the following properties (Java code)

```
public static Builder getDefaultBuilder(String key, String salt, byte[] iv) {
        return new Builder()
                .setIv(iv)
                .setKey(key)
                .setSalt(salt)
                .setKeyLength(128)
                .setKeyAlgorithm("AES")
                .setCharsetName("UTF8")
                .setIterationCount(1)
                .setDigestAlgorithm("SHA1")
                .setBase64Mode(Base64.DEFAULT)
                .setAlgorithm("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
                .setSecureRandomAlgorithm("SHA1PRNG")
                .setSecretKeyType("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    }
```

This is my code so far (C#)

```
public string DecryptText(string encryptedString)
    {
        using (myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            myRijndael.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptionKey);
            myRijndael.IV = new byte[16];
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            Byte[] ourEnc = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);
            string ourDec = DecryptStringFromBytes(ourEnc, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

            return ourDec;
        }
    }

protected string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold 
        // the decrypted text. 
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;

    }
```

But when I try to decrypt I get the following  exception "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.'
".

The origin of the Java code resides here
https://github.com/simbiose/Encryption/blob/master/Encryption/main/se/simbio/encryption/Encryption.java

This is the Java code when encrypting

```
public String encrypt(String data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    if (data == null) return null;
    SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(hashTheKey(mBuilder.getKey()));
    byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(mBuilder.getCharsetName());
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(mBuilder.getAlgorithm());
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, mBuilder.getIvParameterSpec(), mBuilder.getSecureRandom());
    return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes), mBuilder.getBase64Mode());
}

private SecretKey getSecretKey(char[] key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(mBuilder.getSecretKeyType());
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key, mBuilder.getSalt().getBytes(mBuilder.getCharsetName()), mBuilder.getIterationCount(), mBuilder.getKeyLength());
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), mBuilder.getKeyAlgorithm());
}


private char[] hashTheKey(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(mBuilder.getDigestAlgorithm());
    messageDigest.update(key.getBytes(mBuilder.getCharsetName()));
    return Base64.encodeToString(messageDigest.digest(), Base64.NO_PADDING).toCharArray();
}
```

I've been struggling with this for two day since I haven't really worked a lot with encryption, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Update:
Whole class

```
public sealed class MyCryptoClass
{
    protected RijndaelManaged myRijndael;

    private static string encryptionKey = "random";

    // Singleton pattern used here with ensured thread safety
    protected static readonly MyCryptoClass _instance = new MyCryptoClass();
    public static MyCryptoClass Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public MyCryptoClass()
    {

    }

    public string DecryptText(string encryptedString)
    {
        using (myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            myRijndael.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptionKey);
            myRijndael.IV = new byte[16];
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            Byte[] ourEnc = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);
            string ourDec = DecryptStringFromBytes(ourEnc, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

            return ourDec;
        }
    }


    public string EncryptText(string plainText)
    {
        using (myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {

            myRijndael.Key = HexStringToByte(encryptionKey);
            myRijndael.IV = HexStringToByte(initialisationVector);
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(plainText, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
            string encString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

            return encString;
        }
    }


    protected byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
        return encrypted;

    }

    protected string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold 
        // the decrypted text. 
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;

    }

    public static void GenerateKeyAndIV()
    {
        // This code is only here for an example
        RijndaelManaged myRijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
        myRijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        myRijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        myRijndaelManaged.GenerateIV();
        myRijndaelManaged.GenerateKey();
        string newKey = ByteArrayToHexString(myRijndaelManaged.Key);
        string newinitVector = ByteArrayToHexString(myRijndaelManaged.IV);
    }

    protected static byte[] HexStringToByte(string hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesCount = (hexString.Length) / 2;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesCount];
            for (int x = 0; x < bytesCount; ++x)
            {
                bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't they key length set to 128 in the Java code?
"setKeyLength(128)"

Comment: My experience with encryption/decryption is rather limited, so please bear with me.
How can I make sure it's the same length? And which length corresponds to 128?

And what about the SHA1 hashing which is going on, does that matter?

Comment: I've updated the post with the whole class in C#.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For AES-128 a KeySize of 128 and a BlockSize of 128 has to be used.

So I wonder if  `myRijndael.KeySize = 128` and `myRijndael.BlockSize = 128` is missing in your code?

Comment: I've just added 

myRijndael.KeySize = 128;
myRijndael.BlockSize = 128;

But the problem is that it crashes on this line
myRijndael.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptionKey);

I think it's because the original encrypted key is hashed?

Comment: Then I would first check if encryptionKey is really base64 encoded. I would assume not. There are base64 en-/decoder available online.

Comment: How big is encryptionKey after base64 decode? It must be 32, 48, or 64 bytes.

Comment: It is base64 encoded, if you look at the Java code it Base64 encodes it.

@bartonjs I will check the length.

Comment: Yes MyCryptoClass.encryptionKey is the same key used to encrypt it from the Java Encryption.Builder.mKey. The plaintext version before generation of SecretKey.

My guess is also I'm missing SHA-1 hashing and Base64 encoding (decoding?).

I'm not sure I understand what you mean with a test case, is it if I can provide a Salt, Key, Plain text and encrypted text from Java?

Comment: @AndroidCoder can you post your full C# class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Since your `MyCryptoClass.encryptionKey` corresponds to your `Encryption.Builder.mKey` you have to generate the secret key on the C#-side i.e. you have to implement on the C# side a counterpart for each Java-method involved in this process. These Java-methods are `getSecretKey(char[] key)`, `hashTheKey(String key)` and also `third.part.android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byte[] input, int flags)`.
- Possible C#-Counterpart of the Java-method `getSecretKey(char[] key)`:

  ```
  private static byte[] GetSecretKey()
  {
       string hashedKey = GetHashedKey();
       byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);                                                // builder.mCharsetName = "UTF8";
       int iterations = 1;                                                                             // builder.mIterationCount = 1
       byte[] secretKey = null;
       using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(hashedKey, saltBytes, iterations))   // builder.mSecretKeyType = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
       {
            secretKey = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);                                                          // builder.mKeyLength = 128;
            //Console.WriteLine("Key: " + ByteArrayToHexString(secretKey));
       }
       return secretKey;
   }
  ```

  This method derives a secret key using `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` with a key, salt, iterationcount and key length as input. The key (more precisely password) used here is a base64-encoded SHA1-hash from `MyCryptoClass.encryptionKey` provided by `GetHashedKey()` (see below).
- Possible C#-Counterpart of the Java-method `hashTheKey(String key)`:

  ```
  private static string GetHashedKey()
  {
       string hashBase64 = String.Empty;
       using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())                                  // builder.mDigestAlgorithm = "SHA1";
       {
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey));   // builder.mCharsetName = "UTF8";
            hashBase64 = Base64ThirdPartAndroid(hash, true);
            //Console.WriteLine("Hash (base64): " + hashBase64);
       }
       return hashBase64;
   }
  ```

  This method derives a `SHA1`-hash from `MyCryptoClass.encryptionKey` and base64-encodes that hash. For the base64-encoding the method `Base64ThirdPartAndroid(byte[] arr, bool withoutPadding)` (see below) is used.
- Possible C#-Counterpart of the Java-method `third.part.android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byte[] input, int flags)` ( https://github.com/simbiose/Encryption/blob/master/Encryption/main/third/part/android/util/Base64.java):

  ```
  private static string Base64ThirdPartAndroid(byte[] arr, bool withoutPadding)
  {
       string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
       if (withoutPadding) base64String = base64String.TrimEnd('='); // Remove trailing "="-characters
       base64String += "\n";                                         // Append LF (10)
       //Console.WriteLine("Array as base64 encoded string: " + base64String);
       return base64String;
  }
  ```

  In the Java code `third.part.android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byte[] input, int flags)` is used with `flags = Base64.NO_PADDING` which removes the "="-character at the end of the base64-encoded string. Additionally a line feed (LF, `\n`, ASCII value: 10) is appended. If a Base64-Encoding is used which doesn't remove the "="-characters or without a terminating line feed, the decryption will fail since the hash is the base of the later generated secret key which have to match on the encryption and on the decryption side. To the best of my knowledge there is no Base64-encoding on the C# side with the necessary characteristics. However, if there is such an encoding you can use it of course.
- Add all three C#-counterparts to your `MyCryptoClass class`.
- Additionally (to the static field `encryptionKey`) add the static fields `initialisationVector`, `salt` and `secretKey` to your `MyCryptoClass`-class and assign the following values for testing purposes:

  ```
  private static string encryptionKey = "A7zb534OPq59gU7q";
  private static string salt = "JV5k9GoH";
  private static byte[] initialisationVector = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("l4iG63jN9Dcg6537");
  private static byte[] secretKey = GetSecretKey();
  ```

  The type of the parameters corresponds to the type in the Java code (`encryptionKey` and `salt` are strings, the `initialisationVector` is a byte-array). The secret key generated by `GetSecretKey()` is stored in the byte-array `secretKey`.
- In your C# `DecryptText`- and `EncryptText`-method set `myRijndael.Key` and `myRijndael.IV` to

  ```
  myRijndael.Key = secretKey;
  myRijndael.IV = initialisationVector;
  ```
- Test the modifications as follows:

  - With your Java `encrypt`-method encrypt the following plain text:

    ```
    Test: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog...
    ```

    using the key/salt/iv above with

    ```
    mBuilder = Builder.getDefaultBuilder("A7zb534OPq59gU7q","JV5k9GoH","l4iG63jN9Dcg6537".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ```
  - The encrypted text is:

    ```
    mL4ajZtdRgD8CtGSfJGkT24Ebw4SrGUGKQI6bvBw1ziCO/J7SeLiyIw41zumTHMMD9GOYK+kR79CVcpoaHT9TQ==
    ```
  - Decrypting this using the C# `DecryptText`-method gives again the plain text. Below are two test cases:

    ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         // Test 1: Encrypted text from C#
         MyCryptoClass mcc = MyCryptoClass.Instance;
         string encryptedText = mcc.EncryptText("This is a plain text which needs to be encrypted...");
         Console.WriteLine("Encrypted text (base64): " + encryptedText);
         string decryptedText = mcc.DecryptText(encryptedText);
         Console.WriteLine("Decrypted text: " + decryptedText);

         // Test 2: Encrypted text from Java
         string javaEncryptedText = "mL4ajZtdRgD8CtGSfJGkT24Ebw4SrGUGKQI6bvBw1ziCO/J7SeLiyIw41zumTHMMD9GOYK+kR79CVcpoaHT9TQ==";
         Console.WriteLine("Encrypted text from Java (base64): " + javaEncryptedText);
         string javaDecryptedText = mcc.DecryptText(javaEncryptedText);
         Console.WriteLine("Decrypted text from Java: " + javaDecryptedText);
    }
    ```

Comment: @AndroidCoder can you post your full C# class

Answer (score 1):

Following is Full C# class which i were able to work as it is like java class
At the moment i have only checked encryption part

```
 public sealed class MyCryptoClass
    {
        protected AesManaged myRijndael;

        private static string encryptionKey = "MyKey";
        private static string salt = "Mysalt";
        private static byte[] initialisationVector = new byte[16];
        //private static byte[] initialisationVector = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("l4iG63jN9Dcg6537");
        private static byte[] secretKey = GetSecretKey();


        // Singleton pattern used here with ensured thread safety
        protected static readonly MyCryptoClass _instance = new MyCryptoClass();
        public static MyCryptoClass Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }

        public MyCryptoClass()
        {

        }
        public string DecryptText(string encryptedString)
        {
            using (myRijndael = new AesManaged())
            {
                myRijndael.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptionKey);
                myRijndael.IV = new byte[16];
                myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                Byte[] ourEnc = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);
                string ourDec = DecryptStringFromBytes(ourEnc, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

                return ourDec;
            }
        }
        public string EncryptText(string plainText)
        {
            using (myRijndael = new AesManaged())
            {

                myRijndael.Key = secretKey;
                myRijndael.IV = initialisationVector;
                myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(plainText, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
                string encString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

                return encString;
            }
        }
        protected byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijAlg.Key = Key;
                rijAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {

                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
            return encrypted;

        }
        protected string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            // Declare the string used to hold 
            // the decrypted text. 
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijAlg.Key = Key;
                rijAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return plaintext;
        }

        public static void GenerateKeyAndIV()
        {
            // This code is only here for an example
            AesManaged myRijndaelManaged = new AesManaged();
            myRijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            myRijndaelManaged.GenerateIV();
            myRijndaelManaged.GenerateKey();
            string newKey = ByteArrayToHexString(myRijndaelManaged.Key);
            string newinitVector = ByteArrayToHexString(myRijndaelManaged.IV);
        }

        protected static byte[] HexStringToByte(string hexString)
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesCount = (hexString.Length) / 2;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesCount];
                for (int x = 0; x < bytesCount; ++x)
                {
                    bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
                }
                return bytes;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString();
        }

        private static byte[] GetSecretKey()
        {
            string hashedKey = GetHashedKey();
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt); // builder.mCharsetName = "UTF8";
            int iterations = 1; // builder.mIterationCount = 1
            byte[] secretKey = null;
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(hashedKey, saltBytes, iterations)) // builder.mSecretKeyType = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
            {
                secretKey = rfc2898.GetBytes(16); // builder.mKeyLength = 128;
                //Console.WriteLine("Key: " + ByteArrayToHexString(secretKey));
            }
            return secretKey;
        }

        private static string GetHashedKey()
        {
            string hashBase64 = String.Empty;
            using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed()) // builder.mDigestAlgorithm = "SHA1";
            {
                byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey)); // builder.mCharsetName = "UTF8";

                hashBase64 = Base64ThirdPartAndroid(hash, true);
                //hashBase64 = Base64ThirdPartAndroid(hash, true);
                //Console.WriteLine("Hash (base64): " + hashBase64);
            }
            return hashBase64;
        }

        private static string Base64ThirdPartAndroid(byte[] arr, bool withoutPadding)
        {
            string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
            if (withoutPadding) base64String = base64String.TrimEnd('='); // Remove trailing "="-characters
            base64String += "\n"; // Append LF (10)
            //Console.WriteLine("Array as base64 encoded string: " + base64String);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

this method is 100% working for encryption

```
public static string AESDecrypt(string text, string secretKey)
        {
            try
            {
                SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
                RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();

                byte[] finalKey = new byte[16]; // Used to generate finalKey
                byte[] byteDataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(text); // Converting Base64 data to Byte Array
                byte[] byteSecretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey); // Converting secret key in byte array
                byte[] hashSecretKey = sha.ComputeHash(byteSecretKey); // geneating hash in byte array of secret key

                Array.Copy(hashSecretKey, finalKey, 16); // copying fist 16 bytes from hashed secret key to finaly key which to use in algo

                aes.KeySize = 128;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                aes.Key = finalKey;

                using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, null)) //Passing IV as NULL because IV is not present in the Java Code
                {
                    byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(byteDataToDecrypt, 0, byteDataToDecrypt.Length);
                    decrypt.Dispose();
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Comment: please add some explanation along with your code

Comment: The usage of AES in **ECB mode** is **UNSECURE** and should not longer supported. Same to a "key derivation" taken from the passphrase and converted via ".getBytes" and hashing to the secret key - better use **PBKDF2** or **Argon2**. So please **do not use** this peace of software, thanks.